# How to set sample input size with different width in different channels to Conv1d in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I'm new at deep learning and I'm writing a 1D CNN model to train my dataset. Each data in the dataset contains three channels: `(raw_data, sex, age)`. The sample rate of `raw_data` is 50Hz, and window size is 2 seconds, which means 100 samples in one data. So my data will look like this
`([1,2,3,4,...,100],[1],[20])` where `[1]` means sex and `[20]` means age.

Now I want to put this data into my 1D CNN model. I know that `nn.Conv1d(batch_size, channel, width)`. If `width` in all channels are the same, there is no problem. But in my case, `raw_data` contains 100 elements, `sex` and `age` only contain 1 element. How can I put this into my Conv1d layer?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!